# Convert date into datetime format c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a problem with converting datetime, I do not see where I make a mistake.
I think it should be somewhere to date a date for the same sql query to recognize
This is the result I get when I set up a break point
[image]
This is the result at the base

[image]

This is my code with which I send the data

```
var arravialDates = dataAccess.get_dates(userID, date, DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month)); //get dates for user

//working hours

DateTime dateH = new DateTime(2099, 12, 12, 0, 0, 0);
bool hasDate = false;
for (int i = 0; i < arravialDates.Count; i++)
{
     var arravial = dataAccess.getPraesenzzeit(arravialDates[i], userID);
     int index = 0;
}
```

Comment: Just stop building SQL like that. Use parameterized SQL instead. As well as fixing this sort of conversion issue, you'll also avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Dates have no format, either in C# or SQL. They are binary values. Pass the *DateTime* instance as a parameter to a parameterized query. If you don't want to use ADO.NET and SqlCommand directly, use a microORM like Dapper

Comment: BTW *don't* post images of the code that causes the problem, post the *code*. Don't force people to retype the code to check it or post a fix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your screenshot shows a `.Query<>` method. `SqlConnection` has no `Query` method.

Dapper does, a microORM used to make writing parameterized queries *easier*. You *don't* need string interpolation or concatenation when using Dapper or any other ORM. Just write :

```
var output=connection.Query<PRAESENZZEIT>(
                "select * from Z_PRAESENZZEIT " + 
                "where ZPZ_Datum = @date and ZPZ_LPE_ID= @id "
                "order by ZPZ_ID_ASC", 
                new {date=DatTime.Today,id=1});
```

Better yet :

```
var query = "select * from Z_PRAESENZZEIT " + 
            "where ZPZ_Datum = @date and ZPZ_LPE_ID= @id "
            "order by ZPZ_ID_ASC", 

var output=connection.Query<PRAESENZZEIT>(query,new {date=date,id=userid});
```

Answer (score 3):

You are wrong in your approach. You should never create a SQL statement through string concatenation. You are prone to SQL injection, you will experience formatting problems on different systems, and you will have a high impact on the performance of the query parser.

The solution is to use parameterized queries: you add a placeholder for a parameter and add the value through the command parameters.

Your SQL should look like `where ZPZ_Datum = @zpzdate`, then you add a parameter with the name `zpzdate`: `command.Parameters.Add("@zpzdate", arravial);`.